# RLE compression in c

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that does RLE compression to an input string that gives a user but when i try to run it i come with segmentation faut error but i dont know where is my mistake...

here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * rle_convert(char str[500]);

char str_out[500];

int main(void) {
    char str[500];
    printf("give a string : ");
    fgets (str, 500, stdin );
    strcpy(str,rle_convert(str));
    printf("%s",str);
}

char * rle_convert(char str[500]) {
    int i,j,k=0,sum;
    for (i=0; i<(strlen(str)-1); i+sum) {
            sum=1;
            for (j=i; str[j]==str[j++]; j++ ) sum++;
            if (sum>1) {
                    str_out[k]=sum+48;
                    str_out[k++]=str[i];
            }
            else str_out[k]=str[i];
            k++;
    }
    return str_out;
}
```

Comment: rewrite `for (j=i; str[j]==str[j++]; j++ ) sum++;` in 2 or more statements.

Comment: Why not printf() at some strategic points in your program, to get an idea which parts of the code run and which parts don't? In this way you will have a better idea where to focus your debugging efforts.

Comment: Yet another string termination bug.

Answer (score 1):

One bug is here:

```
for (i=0; i<(strlen(str)-1); i+sum) {
                             ^^^^^
```

Did you mean to write `i += sum`?

Another bug is due to the double increment in:

```
        for (j=i; str[j]==str[j++]; j++ ) sum++;
                              ^^^   ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see right off the bat is that you're incrementing `j` twice in each iteration. Perhaps you meant `str[j] == str[j+1]` as the condition. But, even if you do that, in that nested loop you can still reach territory out of your array's bounds. You need to make sure that not only the above condition is true, but *also* that `str[j]` is still within valid range.

Later on, you say

```
str_out[k]=sum+48;
str_out[k++]=str[i];
```

That's definitely not what you want. What you want is probably `str_out[k++]` in both assignments, otherwise the second assignment cancels out the first.

Then again, if `sum` is equal to `1`, you don't save the count of repetitions, only the character. I doubt that's what you want, because the code that would decode the resulting array will not be able to distinguish between count and value. So, you probably want to use the `if` body for both cases (non-conditionally).

Also, as mentioned in another answer, the first loop will continue forever, because you're not incrementing `i` in the step part of the outer `for` loop.